# How to map a call to a system function using the current filename?

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, filetype-tex

I've been using vim for a little while and I'm doing some LaTeX with it, using [Tectonic](https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic) as the engine.

What I was doing to generate the pdf (without leaving the editor)

```
:call system("tectonic main.tex")
```

this works but it's extremely repetitive. After reading a little about it, I've managed to create a simple mapping.

```
map <C-t> :call system("tectonic main.tex") <CR>
```

Which is less repetitive, but still has a hard-coded filename. Is there a way to specify that the map should be applied to the current file? Also can one concatenate operations so it saves (`:w`) first then applies `tectonic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29):

```
expand({expr} [, {nosuf} [, {list}]])               *expand()*
        Expand wildcards and the following special keywords in {expr}.
        'wildignorecase' applies.

        When {expr} starts with '%', '#' or '<', the expansion is done
        like for the |cmdline-special| variables with their associated
        modifiers.  Here is a short overview:

            %       current file name
            #       alternate file name
            #n      alternate file name n
            <cfile>     file name under the cursor
            <cword>     word under the cursor
            <cWORD>     WORD under the cursor

        Modifiers:
            :p      expand to full path
            :h      head (last path component removed)
            :t      tail (last path component only)
            :r      root (one extension removed)
            :e      extension only

        Example:
            :let &tags = expand("%:p:h") . "/tags"
```

You could use something like this:

```
nnoremap <C-t> :call system("tectonic " . expand('%'))<CR>
```

To chain it with the `:w` command you can use an escaped pipe like this:

```
nnoremap <C-t> :w \| call system("tectonic " . expand('%'))<CR>
```

---

Also remember to use `nore` in your mapping and to give a mode (here `n`)

Comment: Thanks! This is really what I was looking for! (Also thanks for `nnoremap`!)

Comment: What about `:make` & `'makeprg'` here?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That would be the right way to go indeed but I assumed that if OP doesn't know about `expand()` they are probably still learning how to use Vim and will have time to learn the basic feature before they begin to use `:make` (and I was being lazy, ok :) )

Comment: @statox when im not being lazy maybe ill write my own answer :P